# Codeigniter Pagination displays links but returns NO Data

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I do not include pagination i.a. comment out `$this->db->limit` and remove `$limit` & `$start` from the `get_category_posts()` method, the values are displayed as they're meant to in a table. However, as soon as adding the limit the links are displayed but not the 'posts'. I feel there is something wrong with the pagination setup or limit business, or maybe even the position of where I have `$this->db->limit` (currently undernearth `$this->db->from('posts')`. I've been up all night trying to get this working and have have no luck on the internet, most people seem to have problems with dislaying links not actually the data itself. If somebody could point me in the direction that would be incredibly appreciated. Thank you.

MODEL:

```
public function get_category_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit, $start){
    if($slug === FALSE){
        $this->db->select('post_id, user_id_fk, post_title, post_content, post_date, slug, username');
        $this->db->join('category_link_table', 'posts.post_id = category_link_table.post_id_fk');
        $this->db->join('category', 'category_link_table.cat_id_fk = category.cat_id');
        $this->db->join('users', 'posts.user_id_fk = users.user_id');
        $this->db->from('posts');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->where('category.parent_id', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $data [] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
        //return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function catpage(){
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . "post/catpage";
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->post_model->record_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_category_posts(null, $config['per_page'], $page);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('posts/catpage', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

VIEW:

```
<?php if(isset($posts) & ($posts <> NULL)){
    foreach($posts as $post_item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><p><a href="<?php echo site_url('post/' . $post_item->slug);?>"><?php echo $post_item->post_title; ?></a></p></td>
            <td><p><?php echo $post_item->username; ?></p></td>
            <td><p><?php echo $post_item->post_date; ?></p></td>
            <td>Rating data</td>
            <td>View data</td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    endforeach; 
}?>
```

Also I have a page that deals with individual slugs, so therefore I pass `NULL` into the methods as it of course requests 3 parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly means *"the links are displayed but not the 'posts'."*? Does it mean, that your `foreach` in your view runs correctly, but if you click the links they do not work?

Comment: And `isset()` checks if a vairable exists and is not NULL, so you do not have to check `($posts <> NULL)` after `isset($posts)` :-) But that will not solve your issue, just a tiny improvement.

Comment: Also, you provide `$page` to your `get_category_posts()` in the controller, but it expects the offset instead. (which is `$limit * ($page - 1)`.)

Comment: Oh oh right okay. And so yeah the links are displayed. However, when you click on the links no data is displayed or generated from the foreach loop (when i apply the pagination limit etc). Without pagination, the foreach loop displays the values the sameway i.e. $post_item->username. I just used var_dump and it appears the query is NULL.

Comment: About which links are we talking right now? :-) I talked about the `<a></a>` links inside your `foreach`. Can you please clarify what links you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry I mean the paginated links which display correctly. I outputted them simply using echo $links, which works, however the data isn't produced yes.

Comment: Please provide a link (the domain does not matter) that is generated from the pagination.

Comment: So you're asking for the link in the URL that appears when clicking on my paginated (1, 2) pages?

Comment: I mean a link from the pagination itself. For example a link to page three. Should be something like *example.com/index.php/post/catpage/3*

Comment: Okay so page when the paginated link is on (1) I am at 
 codeigniter/post/catpage but when on (2) post/catpage/2

Comment: Can you please debug `$page` to make sure it works correclty and apply the correct calculation for the offset from my previous comment to make sure, that the type of `$start` is an integer. If you use the same calculation the default value for `$page` would be needed to be `1` instead of `0`. (Which can be shortened by `$page = $this->uri->segement(3, 1);`)

Comment: You can also improve your code by removing the neccessarity of talking with `$this->uri->segemnt()` at all by adding `$page` as a parameter to `catpage() {` like `public function catpage(int page = 1) {`

Comment: Okay I changed made the following changes in the model: $offset = ($start-1) * limit < is in the same order as the get_category post in model and controller. So in the controller get_category_posts "offset" is the $page. I also changed the segment to 3:1 but it does not change the URI for page1 but page2 still shows (2). Also The get posts returns NULL when I use var_dump so would that be due to this offset issue or an issue with the query?